# Why is a question from ignored tags showing in my feed

Tags: discussion, support

In My questions page, I see the following:

[image]

As you can see, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146397/i-cant-add-a-server-to-minecraft-pocket-edition-v0-8-0) appears to be greyed out as if it has been deleted when it's evidently not deleted at all.

<s>Why is it displaying that way?</s>

**EDIT:** Ah sorry I just noticed that I had added [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) as ignored tag a while back and had forgotten about it.

[image]

When I opened the community the question appeared that way. So new question is, Why is a question from an ignored tag showing up in my feed?

Comment: Because all ignoring a tag does is make them greyed out. Not actually remove them.

Comment: @Arperum Yes that's correct. Just found the answer on Meta Stack Exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [this Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do):

> Ignored Tags: **Questions with these tags are shown faded; they are
>   still visible but less prominent**. Checking the "Hide Ignored Tags"
>   box causes them to be hidden completely. (This is done by a
>   client-side script however, so you may notice odd "gaps.")

So it appears I was mistaken about what the ignored tags do.